# How to use Grgit to fetch from remote?

Tags: grgit

The following code:

```
final git = Grgit.open("${oldVersionRoot}/.git")
git.fetch(refSpecs: ["release/${oldVersion}"])
```

emits:

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: Remote does not have release/2.1747.0 available for fetch.
```

What's the right incantation to get `fetch` to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://github.com/ajoberstar/gradle-git/issues/166:

https://github.com/ajoberstar/grgit/blob/master/src/test/groovy/org/ajoberstar/grgit/operation/FetchOpSpec.groovy#L115 indicates using:

```
git.fetch(refSpecs: ["refs/remotes/origin/release/${oldVersion}"])
```